# MongoDB - Aggregation on multiple distinct values

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a query which will count the number of documents which have both distinct values for column 1 and column 2.

Here's what I've tried so far which works for 1 column, how would I go about adding in a second column so it only retrieves data when both values are unique?

> db.eventDB.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "column1" } }, {     $group: {      _id: 1,       count: {         $sum: 1       }     }   } ] );

Comment: Something like `db.eventDB.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : {column1: "$column1", column2: "$column2"}}}, {$count: count }] )`

Comment: Post your sample document

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.eventDB.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id: { column1: "$column1", column2: "$column2" }, count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: This will return each column and a count - how do I get the global sum?

`{ "_id" : { "column2" : "01579b7ee1e0001d8cd9771e5e751404800ae00d008b0" }, "count" : 33 }`